# Como gerar Classe TRemotable com Bind de XML?

Tags: xml, delphi

Estou precisando gerar as classes TRemotable de uma WebService SOAP com base em um XML. Tentei o Bind de XML do Delphi XE mas ele gera interface com uses uses xmldom, XMLDoc, XMLInt.

Answer (score 2):

Para gerar o cliente para um `WebService` no Delphi, você deve usar o Assistente de importação de WSDL, utilizando os seguintes passos:

1. Inicie o Delphi XE
2. Ative o menu **File -> New -> Other...**
3. Na janela mostrada, selecione a opção Delphi **Projects -> Webservices**
4. No painel à direita escolha **WSDL Importer**

O Assistente de Importação do WSDL do Webservice vai gerar uma `unit` com as classes que você precisa.